# creating an empty dataframe and populating rows later

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create an empty dataframe and then populate it with rows. I am unaware of the column names and index at the time of dataframe declaration.

For Example, I want some code like below.

```
df_local = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(0, 2):
    some logic ......
    var_1 = a dataframe object
df_local.loc[i] = var_1
```

Here `var_1` is a Pandas object, populated amid the code inside the for loop for every `i`.

For Example

```
For i = 0, Var_1 =

    bam  ham       jam      kam      lam       mam       pam    tam
0    0    0      0.823909    0     1.30103    0.823909    1    0  

For i = 1 , Var_1 = 
    bam  ham       jam      kam      lam       mam       pam    tam
1    1    2      0.823909    1     1.30103      4         1      0
```

The output I want looks like:

```
df_local =

    bam  ham       jam      kam      lam       mam       pam    tam
0    0    0      0.823909    0     1.30103    0.823909    1      0       
1    1    2      0.823909    1     1.30103      4         1      0
```

I tried using append, but did not get any output.

Comment: Why do you need this? Especially as you can use [`loc/.ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement) to set with enlargement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you just concatenate?

```
var_1 = pd.DataFrame({'bam': [0], 'ham': [1], 'jam': [0.5]})
var_2 = pd.DataFrame({'bam': [1], 'ham': [0], 'mam': [2]})

>>> pd.concat([var_1, var_2], ignore_index=True)
   bam  ham  jam  mam
0    0    1  0.5  NaN
1    1    0  NaN    2
```

Comment: Oh , that was easy , Thanks a lot :)