# Initializing an empty DataFrame and appending rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, concatenation

Different from [creating an empty dataframe and populating rows later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33088841/creating-an-empty-dataframe-and-populating-rows-later) , I have many many dataframes that needs to be concatenated.

If there were only two data frames, I can do this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=list('AB'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[5, 6], [7, 8]], columns=list('AB'))

df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
```

Imagine I have millions of `df` that needs to be appended/concatenated each time I read a new file into a DataFrame object.

But when I tried to initialize an empty dataframe and then adding the new dataframes through a loop:

```
import pandas as pd
alldf = pd.DataFrame(, columns=list('AB'))
for filename in os.listdir(indir):
    df = pd.read_csv(indir+filename, delimiter=' ')
    alldf.append(df, ignore_index=True)
```

This would return an empty `alldf` with only the header row, e.g.

```
alldf = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('AB'))
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=list('AB'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[5, 6], [7, 8]], columns=list('AB'))
for df in [df1, df2]:
    alldf.append(df, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Are you just getting tripped up because DataFrame.append doesn't happen in-place (unlike list.append)?  If so, this is a dup of something, I'm sure.  [And you really don't want to use append, you want to read everything first and concatenate -- append would be insanely slow.]

Comment: Thanks @DSM, kind of. I would have thought, append won't do anything until there's some sort of `pd.commit()` like a DB =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df.concat()` over an array of dataframes is probably the way to go, especially for clean CSVs. **But** in case you suspect your CSVs are either dirty or could get recognized by `read_csv()` with mixed types between files, you may want to explicity create each dataframe in a loop.

You can initialize a dataframe for the first file, and then each subsequent file start with an empty dataframe based on the first.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=df1.columns,index=df1.index)
```

This takes the structure of dataframe `df1` but no data, and create `df2`. If you want to force data type on columns, then you can do it to `df1` when it is created, before its structure is copied.

*[more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30355286/2327328)*

Answer (score -1):

From @DSM comment, this works:

```
import pandas as pd
dfs = []
for filename in os.listdir(indir):
    df = pd.read_csv(indir+filename, delimiter=' ')
    dfs.append(df)

alldf = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `dfs.append(df)` ?

Comment: Nope. It's concat.

Comment: this line: `dfs(df)`. dfs is an array, not a function.